# React virtualized list not rendering on browser zoom out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accordion, react-virtualized

So this is a bit weird issue.

I have an accordion where each panel contains a react virtualized list. Everything works perfect... Problem is:

- If one panel is open...
- The browser is zoomed out...
- another panel is opened...

**The list does not render...**

This seems to occur when the value of window.devicePixelRatio is less than 1. While debugging into react-virtualized it seems like childrenToDisplay in Grid is empty due to failing this check on line 903 in Grid.js:
// Render only enough columns and rows to cover the visible area of the grid.

```
if (height > 0 && width > 0) {
```

Possibly due to low devicePixelRatio, some initial pixel value (maybe set to 1px?) becomes 0px.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This sort of question needs a repro. Sounds pretty specific.